# df grouping rows with same dates

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame for hours loged for all weeks in 2018,

```
        Start Date  Resource:       tHours Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday  Sunday 
    0   07/01/2018  Joe, John       18.0    6       6           0       0       6       0       0   
    1   07/01/2018  Joe, John       21.0    2       2           8       8       3       0       0   
    2   14/01/2018  Joe, John       12.0    4       0           2       4       2       0       0   
    3   14/01/2018  Joe, John       12.0    4       0           2       4       2       0       0   
    4   14/01/2018  Joe, John       15.0    0       8           4       0       3       0       0   
    ...
    36 01/04/2018   Joe, John       8.0     8       0           0       0       0       0       0
    37 01/04/2018   Joe, John       23.0    0       8           8       4       3       0       0
    38 01/04/2018   Joe, John       8.0     0       8           0       4       4       0       0
```

I want to group/merged/concatenate (not sure the correct name for it) by dates 
  I used "`df.groupby('Start Date', as_index=False).sum()`"
    got this output

```
     Start Date   Resource:         tHours Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday  Sunday 
1   01/04/2018  Joe, John           39      8       8           8       8       7       0       0   
..      
10  07/01/2018  Joe, John           41      8       8           8       8       9       0       0   
..      
22  14/01/2018  Joe, John           39      8       8           8       8       7       0       0
```

What the best code to order by date from the start of the year to the end of year?. the date are in the mm/dd/yy format

Comment: [df.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: when i uses "df.groupby('Start Date', as_index=False).sum().sort_values(by=['Start Date'])"  i am still getting the same result

Do I need to convert the dates to dd/mm/yy

Comment: is `df['Start Date']` datetime or a string

Comment: df.info() 
....
"Start Date                       159 non-null object"

so it would be a String

Comment: convert it to [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) then sort

Comment: @SeánReidy just FIY, merging and concatenating means you have 2 dataframes that you want to combine together a certain way.

Comment: Can you show and explain HOW you want the final dataframe to look? From your question it looks like you are getting the desired results.

Comment: I have dates in the data set as dd/mm/yyyy
I want to group all the same dates 
when I used "df.groupby('Start Date', as_index=False).sum().sort_values(by=['Start Date'])"
its sorteing by mm/dd/yyyy but need it by dd/mm/yyyy